# how read mixed binary/text file with io::Cursor and byteorder?

Tags: rust

I wanna read/parse a data file mixed binary/text. This file isn't utf_8 format and can't be converted.

The structure of the header of my data file is :

```
#[derive(Debug)]   
Struct DataParse{
       
       file_num : u16{2}, 
       file_name: char{16},
       file_size: u32{4},
       file_off: u32{4},
       file_dum: u8{1}
    
}
```

I use io::Cursor with the memory buffer and the crate byteorder to operate on my file :

```
use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::fs::File;
use std::path::Path;
use byteorder::{LittleEndian, ReadBytesExt};
use std::io::Cursor;

    fn read_parse_file(path_of_file: &str) -> io::Result<()> {
    
        let path = Path::new(&path_of_file);
        let display = path.display();
        println!("xxx : {}", &display);
    
        let mut f = File::open(&path)?;  
        let mut buffer = vec![0; 27];
    
        f.read_exact(&mut buffer).unwrap(); 
    
        let mut vec_pointer = Cursor::new(buffer);
    
        let filenum = vec_pointer.read_u16::<LittleEndian>().unwrap();
        let filename = // ?????????
        let filesize = vec_pointer.read_u32::<LittleEndian>().unwrap();
        let fileoff = vec_pointer.read_u32::<LittleEndian>().unwrap();
        let filendum = vec_pointer.read_u8().unwrap();
    
        let dat_binary = DataParse {file_num: filenum, file_name: filename, file_size: filesize, file_off: fileoff,  file_dum: filendum  };

        println!("{:?}", dat_binary);

    
        Ok(())
    
    }
```

My question is, how get "Struct file_name" of char type in a mixed binary/text in my case?

Comment: This depends on exactly how you want to store the parsed text in your final struct. Is it a `String`, a `Vec<u8>`, a `[u8; 16]` or a `[char; 16]`? Recall that `char` is a 4-byte number intended to hold Unicode code points, so it might not be what you're looking for.

Comment: @ddulaney : Hmm oki but with a cursor in my final struct, if I wanna store the parsed text in a String, how to do?

String::from_utf8().unwrap()

don't work with std::io::Cursor<std::vec::Vec<_>>

Comment: `from_utf8` relies on you allocating a new `Vec` and pre-filling it. `vec![0u8; 16]` to allocate a 16-byte vec, then `read_exact` on the cursor to read into it, then pass it into `String::from_utf8`.

Comment: @ddulaney: Thanks for your help. Really appreciated. I have a last question.

Here the output console of my code :

`file_num: 2621, filename_of_ressource:"LESSON.BIN\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}", size: 792, off: 65536, dum: 0`

This is what I was looking for so it's ok but each filename have a different lenght. And I can't define it in advance. How correct this :

`LESSON.BIN\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}` to this : `LESSON.BIN`

Comment: Use [`String::find`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.find) to find the index of the first null, then [`String::truncate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.truncate) to cut off the string there. If there isn't a `\u{0}` character in the string, `find` will return `None`

Comment: @ddulaney It's ok now! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @ddulaney for helping me.

```
fn read_parse_file(path_of_file: &str) -> io::Result<()> {

    let path = Path::new(&path_of_file);
    let display = path.display();
    println!("path is : {}", &display);

    let mut f = File::open(&path)?;

    let mut buffer = vec![0; 27];
    let mut string_buffer = vec![0u8; 16];

    f.read_exact(&mut buffer).unwrap(); 
  
    let mut vec_pointer = Cursor::new(buffer);

    let filenum = vec_pointer.read_u16::<LittleEndian>().unwrap();

    vec_pointer.read_exact(&mut string_buffer).unwrap();
    let mut filename = String::from_utf8(string_buffer).unwrap(); 
    match filename.find('\0'){
        None => {},
        Some(v) => { filename.truncate(v) },   
    }
        
    let filesize = vec_pointer.read_u32::<LittleEndian>().unwrap();
    let fileoff = vec_pointer.read_u32::<LittleEndian>().unwrap();
    let filendum = vec_pointer.read_u8().unwrap();

    let dat_binary = DatBinary {file_num : filenum, filename_of_ressource : filename, size : filesize, off : fileoff, dum : filendum}; 

    println!("{:?}", dat_binary);  

    Ok(())

}
```